Train AI to schedule a league with certain constraints
I need some suggestions on options to look into to train an AI model to schedule sporting events based on certain constraints.  Contraints like no back to back games, 2 games per day, 1 per week, keep at some venue, don't play at the same time as another team, etc.
My idea would be that an AI model would know past games scheduled and move things around when a constraint cant be made with the existing schedule they have in place and wont put that game back if necessary.
It could even learn from past schedules that were done and use certain methods for future schedules to be done for a league.
Base on this what methods or tools should I look into to handle this? If hiring someone what type of skills should they have.
